# can there be concurrency issues when using C# class with only static methods and no variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Have I understood correctly that all threads have copy of method's variables in their own stack so there won't be problems when a static method is called from different threads?

Comment: If it's constraint that tightly - *maybe*. But it doesn't sound like a very interesting method.

Comment: I believe that issues would happen when doing the opposite for example you could have a Public Class that also has access to Static methods can you give an example of code expressing exactly what your confusion is ..?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Yuck Why? Just because a method is *pure*, doesn't mean that it is boring. Functional programming deals almost exclusively with such methods and is still interesting and powerful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes and no.  If the parameters are value types, then yes they have their own copies.  Or if the reference type is immutable, then it can't be altered and you have no issues.  However, if the parameters are mutable reference types, then there are still possible thread safety issues to consider with the arguments being passed in.

Does that make sense?  If you pass a reference type as an argument, it's reference is passed "by value" so it's a new reference that refers back to the old object.  Thus you could have two different threads potentially altering the same object in a non-thread-safe way.

If each of those instances are created and used **only** in the thread using them, then chances are low that you'd get bit, but I just wanted to emphasize that just because you're using static methods with only locals/parameters is not a *guarantee* of thread-safety (same with instance of course as noted by Chris).

Comment: +1 for noting that the use of static (or lack thereof) doesn't guarantee anything- the same rules hold for non-static methods.

Comment: @ChrisShain: Very true, I should have mentioned that explicitly, I was hoping it was implied.

Answer (score 10):

> Have I understood correctly that all threads have copy of method's variables in their own stack so there won't be problems when a static method is called from different threads?

No.

First off, it is false that "all threads have a copy of the method's local variables in their own stack."  A local variable is only generated on the stack when it has a short lifetime; local variables may have arbitrarily long lifetimes if they are (1) closed-over outer variables, (2) declared in an iterator block, or (3) declared in an async method.

In all of those cases a local variable created by an activation of a method on one thread can later be mutated by multiple threads. Doing so is not threadsafe.

Second, there are plenty of possible problems when calling static methods from different threads. The fact that local variables are sometimes allocated on the stack does not magically make access to shared memory by static methods suddenly correct.

> can there be concurrency issues when using C# class with only static methods and no variables?

I assume you mean "no static variables" and not "no local variables".

**Absolutely there can be**. For example, here's a program with no static variables, no non-static methods, no objects created apart from the second thread, and a single local variable to hold a reference to that thread. None of the methods other than the cctor actually *do anything at all*. **This program deadlocks.**  You cannot assume that just because your program is dead simple that it contains no threading bugs!

Exercise to the reader: describe why this program that appears to contain no locks actually deadlocks.

```
class MyClass
{
  static MyClass() 
  {
      // Let's run the initialization on another thread!
      var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(Initialize);
      thread.Start();
      thread.Join();
  }

  static void Initialize() 
  { /* TODO: Add initialization code */ }

  static void Main() 
  { }
}
```

It sounds like you are looking for some magical way of knowing that your program has no threading issues. There is no such magical way of knowing that, short of making it single-threaded. You're going to have to analyze your use of threads and shared data structures.

Comment: The static ctor is guaranteed to complete before any static members (the `Initialize` method in this case) is allowed to execute, but the ctor is busy waiting for the thread that is waiting for that ctor.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo: You've got the right idea. But of course, if the cctor called Initialize without spawning a thread, the call would be allowed even though it is a static member executing before the static constructor has finished running. A more accurate way to state the problem is: If a second thread tries to access a static member while the cctor is running on the first thread, then the second thread skips calling the cctor and waits for the first thread to finish before it accesses the static member. But since in this case the first thread is waiting on the second, deadlock.

Comment: sounds reasonable. The dead lock issue is not obvious from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx), but the [c# specification 17.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) at least gives a hint by noting "at most once in a given application domain".

Comment: I think that SO should devise some kind of automatic warning/filter on those "local variable on the stack" questions/answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such guarantee unless all of the variables are immutable reference types or value types.

If the variables are mutable reference types, proper synchronization needs to be performed.

EDIT: Mutable variables only need to be synchronized if they are shared between threads- locally declared mutables that are not exposed outside of the method need not be synchronized.

Comment: Mutable references declared and used locally don't need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless methods use **only** local scope variable and **no any** gloval variable, so **there is no any way** any of that methods can impact on the state of any object, if this is `true`, you have no problems to use it in multithreading. I would say, that even , in this conditions, `static` they or not, is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If they are variables local to the method then yes, you have nothing to worry about. Just make sure you are not passing parameters by reference or accessing global variables and changing them in different threads. Then you will be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods can refer to data in `static` fields -- either in their class or outside of it -- which may not be thread safe.

So ultimately the answer to your question is "no", because there may be problems, although usually there won't be.

Answer (score 0):

Two threads should still be able to operate on the same object either by the object being passed in to methods on different threads as parameters, or if an object can be accessed globally via Singleton or the like all bets are off.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the answers about why static methods are not necessarily thread-safe, it's worth considering why they might be, and why they often are.

The first reason why they might be is, I think, the sort of case you were thinking of:

```
public static int Max(int x, int y)
{
  return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

This pure function is thread-safe because there is no way for it to affect code on any other thread, the locals `x` and `y` remain local to the thead they are on, not being stored in a shared location, captured in a delegate, or otherwise leaving the purely local context.

It's always worth noting, that combinations of thread-safe operations can be non thread-safe (e.g. doing a thread-safe read of whether a concurrent dictionary has a key followed by a thread-safe read of the value for that key, is not thread-safe as state can change between those two thread-safe operations). Static members tend not to be members that can be combined in such non thread-safe ways in order to avoid this.

A static method may also guarantee it's own thread-safety:

```
public object GetCachedEntity(string key)
{
  object ret;  //local and remains so.
  lock(_cache) //same lock used on every operation that deals with _cache;
    return _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ret) ? ret : null;
}
```

OR:

```
public object GetCachedEntity(string key)
{
  object ret;
  return _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ret) ? ret : null; //_cache is known to be thread-safe in itself!
}
```

Of course here this is no different than an instance member which protects itself against corruption from other threads (by co-operating with all other code that deals with the objects they share).

Notably though, it is very common for static members to be thread-safe, and instance members to not be thread-safe. Almost every static member of the FCL guarantees thread-safety in the documentation, and almost every instance member does not barring some classes specifically designed for concurrent use (even in some cases where the instance member actually is thread-safe).

The reasons are two-fold:

1. The sort of operations most commonly useful for static members are either pure functions (most of the static members of the `Math` class, for example) or read static read-only variables which will not be changed by other threads.
2. It's very hard to bring your own synchronisation to a third-party's static members.

The second point is important. If I have an object whose instance members are not thread-safe, then assuming that calls do not affect non-thread-safe data shared between different instances (possible, but almost certainly a bad design), then if I want to share it between threads, I can provide my own locking to do so.

If however, I am dealing with static members that are not thread-safe, it is much harder for me to do this. Indeed, considering that I may be racing not just with my own code, but with code from other parties, it may be impossible. This would make any such public static member next to useless.

Ironically, the reason that static members tend to be thread-safe is not that it's easier to make them so (though that does cover the pure functions), but that it's harder to! So hard in-fact that the author of the code has to do it for the user, because the user won't be able to themselves.